# Crontab is not running on mac osx 10.9.3

Tags: macos, cron

I would like to open a URL using crontab in the terminal every minute for example. I also tried "cronnix" and "lingos" but non of the methods work. My mashine simply does not execute the command. I did

```
crontab -e
```

then I inserted the line

```
1 * * * * open http://www.google.de/
```

terminal says it is installing the new cron job. But then nothing happens. What do I have to do? Thanks.

Comment: ok. */1 * * * * did it.

Comment: You can omit the /1 part, see my answer for explanation.

Comment: is this still a problem for you or have you solved it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1 * * * *
```

means the job will execute every first minute of every hour of every day of every week of every month, for example at 09:01, 10:01, 11:01, ...

```
*/x * * * *
```

will execute the job every x'th minute of every hour of every (yadda yadda...).
For example, for `x=5` the job will execute at 09:05, 09:10, 09:15, and so on, but also of course at 10:05, 10:10, 10:15, ...
For `x=1` it is the same as just saying

```
* * * * *
```